# How to perform bitwise operations on bitsets of different sizes?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, std-bitset

Is there a way of performing bitwise operations on two `std::bitset`s of different sizes?

Something similar to this:

```
    std::bitset<8> payload { 0b1010'0010 };
    std::bitset<10> segment { 0b00'0000'0000 };
    segment |= payload;
```

For the above example, I basically want to transfer all the 8 bits of `payload` to the lower bits of `segment`. What other options do I have if this cannot be done? Should I write a for loop that uses the subscript `operator[]` to transfer the bits one by one?

Comment: @Captain Obvlious I took a brief look at it. Didn't find anything relevant. Also, I tried std::ranges::copy but that doesn't work since std::bitset does not support iterators??

Comment: @CaptainObvlious you cannot (easily) get iterator from `std::bitset`, as OP said.

Comment: If you're only using "small" bitsets, you could use [`to_ullong`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_ullong) and use normal bit-twiddling and assign the result back.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Yes I guess I'm using small bitsets, maybe max 16 bits. Sounds like a good idea. I'll try ulong.

Comment: use `to_ullong` to convert the smaller bitset to the bigger one, then use `|=`

Comment: Have a look at [bitset2](https://github.com/ClaasBontus/bitset2/). It supports conversion from one type of bitset2 to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the narrower to the wider one then you can use `|=`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main() {
    std::bitset<8> payload { 0b1010'0010 };
    std::bitset<10> segment { 0b00'0000'0000 };
    
    std::bitset<10> x(payload.to_ullong());
    segment |= x;
    std::cout << segment;
}
```

For wider ones you can use `to_string` and the constructor creating the bitset from a string.